# Save Contacts from file to Android device

Tags: android, contacts

How to Take contact numbers from a file to save inside mobile phone.
I can able to extract contacts from mobile phone but could not able to save contacts from some file..
Please Help.. I do not have even any idea how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the contacts were stored on the file. If it's a standard format, like CSV or  vCard, you should be able to import it to your Gmail Contacts. Then your Android phone would have the contacts, assuming that your Google account is linked with your phone.

To do so, log into Gmail, click on the top-left dropbox and select Contacts, click on More, and select Import...

Comment: Oh Thanks i do not know that the contacts in gmail can also come to my mobile devices. I will try it and get back to you again.
Many thanks

Comment: Yes we can able to sink contacts from gmail account.. thnks buddy